# If $\{f_n\}$ and $\{g_n\}$ be uniformly convergent sequences of bounded functions on S, then $\{f_ng_n\}$ is uniformly convergent on S.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, uniform-convergence

If $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly to $f$ and $\{g_n\}$ converges uniformly to $g$, does it mean $\{f_ng_n\} $ will converge uniformly to $fg$?

I am absolutely stuck on this. Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**

\begin{align}||f_ng_n-fg||_\infty&\le||f_ng_n-f_ng+f_ng-fg||_\infty\\&\le||f_n||_\infty||g_n-g||_\infty+||g||_\infty||f_n-f||_\infty\end{align}
and use the hypothesis that those functions are bounded.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not well-acquainted with the || notation, can you please tell me if | will work just as well? We work with | in our classes.

Comment: Yes it works since
$$||f||_\infty=\sup|f|$$

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: It is the norm of uniform convergence. A sequence of functions converges uniformly if and only if the sequence converges in the sup norm.